# Changing display name on per-site Meta when display name on main site is changed

Tags: discussion, display-names

I changed my display name on a Stack Exchange site, but my display name on its Meta remains the same. I know it's easy to change the name on Meta, but based on our Stack Exchange experiences with our display names, should people opt to automatically have their display name on Meta changed?

Not tagging this as a feature request because I'm not even sure if this has to be feature.

Comment: How long have you waited? Because it's probably just caching- Per-site metas cache information from your main account, so things like rep changes (and most likely name changes unless something's changed since my last per-site name change) can take a bit to propagate over.

Comment: I waited two days.

Comment: Sounds like a bug... if it's the case. Can you link to the site/meta that you're having this issue on?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts that aren't connected? The only site you have an account on other than MSE is productivity and you're not a meta user there... Is it possible that you have two different accounts that need to be merged? That would explain why you're not seeing a UN change.

Comment: I took a look - can't find any user of yours that has a different name on the main and on the meta.